# multilevel list without indentation in word vba

Tags: vba, list, ms-word, indentation, multi-level

I have a macro that search `[#]` in document and make it list number, with multilevel. Each hashtag represent level number. i.e

- [#]   level 1  - - result - -> 1.
- [##]  level 2  -- result --> 1.1.
- [###] level 3  -- result --> 1.1.1.

So it's working just fine. But I don't want my text to get indented instead remain in their indent level. as my text is in table so its get crazy when indented.

working code is here:

```
Sub Nummerierung_Numeric()

'Makro Written by M.B.A

Dim Level As Integer

    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find 'or Selection.Range.Find
        .Text = "\[#*\]"
        .MatchWildcards = True
        
        Do While .Execute
        If .Parent.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
                Level = Len(.Parent.Text) - 2
                .Parent.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("1 / 1.1 / 1.1.1")
                .Parent.ListFormat.ListLevelNumber = Level
                .Parent.Delete
        End If
        Loop
        
        .MatchWildcards = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: You change their applied style to onre which does not have inderntation. Ther most logical way of doing this is to define a brew sret of styles that inherit from ther styles you are currently using but which have a different indentation rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the `1 / 1.1 / 1.1.1` style setting such that any paragraph using this style will not have indent but note that this might affect paragraphs that you might want the indentation (in this case you will need to define a new style for this purpose):

```
    Const newNumPos As Long = 0
    Const newTextPos As Long = 18 'Change as required, this is the Text Indent (in Points)
    
    With ActiveDocument.Styles("1 / 1.1 / 1.1.1").ListTemplate
        .ListLevels(1).TextPosition = newTextPos
        .ListLevels(1).NumberPosition = newNumPos
        
        .ListLevels(2).TextPosition = newTextPos
        .ListLevels(2).NumberPosition = newNumPos
                
        .ListLevels(3).TextPosition = newTextPos
        .ListLevels(3).NumberPosition = newNumPos
    End With
```

Comment: although this is not the answer to my question, However you have given me a nice idea. I appreciate it. thanks!

Comment: @IbneAshiq Then you will have to explain `remain in their indent level`, what does that mean?